# x or more successes on n trials, with 3 possible events.

Tags: probability

I'm struggling with calculating the probabilities of dice rolls in an game. In essence, you roll a number of $10$-sided dice, where $1-6$ gives $0$ successes, $7-9$ gives 1 success, and $10$ gives 2 successes. So on each trial have three possible events:

- $0$ successes ($p_0 = 0.6$)
- $1$ success ($p_1 = 0.3$)
- $2$ successes ($p_2 = 0.1$)

How do I calculate the probability of getting x or more successes on n trials in a case such as this?

EDIT:

I considered calculating it via the fraction of possible outcomes that gives an exact amount of successes, basically as $\frac{n!}{n_0!n_1!n_2!}$ where $n_0$ is number of trials giving $0$ successes, $n_1$ and $n_2$ likewise, such that $n = n_0 + n_1 + n_2$, however I cannot figure out how to incorporate the probabilities into this. I tried to get inspiration from the Bernoulli trial $P(k)$ function: $$P(k) = {n \choose k} p^k q^{n-k}$$

but don't know how to translate this to a non-binomial case, or that is even the way to go.

---

I tried using the formula commented by drhab, to calculate the sum of $P$ for all possible combinations of $n_0$, $n_1$ and $n_2$ when $n = 2$, but this only yielded $p = 0.505$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Work it out explicitly for small $n$.  Then get a recursion to handle larger $n$.

Comment: Your effort leads to $P(X=x)=\sum_{n_1+2n_2=x}\frac{n!}{(n-n_1-n_2)!n_1!n_2!}0.6^{n-n_1-n_2}0.3^{n_1}0.1^{n_2}$, but alas, not any further.

Comment: The comment from drhab gives you the formula (not pretty but computable). I don't think there's much more to do. If you want approximations for large $n$ you would apply the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: Another approach is to say $P(X=x)$ is the coefficient of $y^x$ in the expansion of $\left(\frac{7}{10}+\frac{2}{10}y+\frac{2}{10}y^2\right)^n$